# Getting value fom a ResultSet hangs

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc, resultset

I am building a Java application to query a remote SQL database.  I'm able to read all but one of the columns. When I try to read that column, my application just hangs forever without firing any exception or error. Would anyone have an idea why ? Here's all the details :

- The driver I'm using is `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` and Java version 6 update 35;
- That column (#214) isn't any different than any other. To make sure, I did the following System.out:

  - `System.out.println("\t" + resultset.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "\t" + resultset.getMetaData().getColumnDisplaySize(i) + "\t" + resultset.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) +  "\t" + resultset.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(214) + "\t" + resultset.getMetaData().getColumnClassName(i));`
  - The result was : `214 WorkLog 65535   -1  LONGVARCHAR java.lang.String`
- I tried reading the value with `resultset.getString(),resultset.getASCIIStream(),resultset.getCharacterStream()` without any success;

Finally, here's the code :

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:AR");  
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM HPD:HelpDesk WHERE \"CaseID+\" = '000000008815267'");  
while (rs.next()) {  
    for (int i = 1;i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){  
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "\t" + rs.getString(i));  
    }  
}
```

EDIT : The application hangs when trying to read to column. In this case the rs.getString()

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: You need to change your loop to finish at `i <= ...`, not `i < ...`

Comment: `resultset.getMetaData().getColumnType(214)` gives me -1. According to java.SQL.Types, that's LONGVARCHAR

Comment: @Bohemian - You're right, I was missing the final column. It still hangs at the same place tough.

Answer (score 0):

A longvarchar is basically a CLOB.  From what I understand, you need to read this with a stream:

```
BufferedInputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream( rs.getBinaryStream( longvarcharColumnIndex ) );
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int index;
while ( ( int index = bufferedIn.read() ) != -1 )
{
    byteArrayOut.write( ( byte ) index );
}

bufferedIn.close();
byteArrayOut.close();
```

You don't say example where the code is hanging.  Is it on a read()?  Is it on available()?  You have to be very careful of how you call these methods, otherwise the code will freeze in a read() state when there are no more bytes available to read.

Comment: You're right, I did forget that. It hangs while trying to read the value. i.e. rs.getString(). I did try to read it as a CLOB but it still hangs while trying to read (at bufferedIn.read()).